# Deferring the execution of SQL in nested services?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, business-logic

I've started working with services and abstracting my business logic to them. All is going well, and it's great to be able to reuse code in a way that makes sense.

The problem I have hit is demonstrated below in some example code I have put together. As you can see, the person service handles the creating of people and during that process commits the creation of the person. This is all well and good, but when I want to reuse the function elsewhere and the changes shouldn't be commited until the end of that parent function then I have a problem.

I have demonstrated the above in the below service called 'ComplexService' which has a function to create x random people. During the for loop, if it was fail for any reason I would want the changes to  the database not be comitted however in this example it does. How can I get round this?

Services

```
Public Class PersonService
    Implements IPersonService

    Private Property UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork

    Public Sub New(unitOfWork As IUnitOfWork)
        Me.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork
    End Sub

    Public Sub Create(model As NewPersonModel) Implements IPersonService.Create
        Dim person As New Person With {
            .Name = model.Name,
            .DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth,
            .CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
        }
        UnitOfWork.PersonRepository.Add(person)
        UnitOfWork.Commit()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ComplexService
    Implements IComplexService
    Private Property PersonService As IPersonService

    Public Sub New(personService As IPersonService)
        Me.PersonService = personService
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddXRandomPeople(x As Integer) Implements IComplexService.AddXRandomPeople
        For i = 0 To x - 1
            PersonService.Create(
                New NewPersonModel With {
                    .DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now,
                    .Name = "Test"
                }
            )
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Models

```
Public Class NewPersonModel

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property DateOfBirth As Date

End Class

Public Class Person

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property DateOfBirth As Date
    Public Property CreatedAt As Date

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple rule:

> You create it, you own it.

That is, the class that create an object is the one making sure that it is handled properly.

In your case, you transfer the ownage to the `PersonService`. In my opinion that's wrong, since the `PersonService` can't possible know what the calling class intended to do.

What if the calling class wanted to create a person and then an order. If each service commit, the business transaction could end up in an inconsistent state.

Thus the code that invokes both complexService and personService is responsible to commit the UnitOfWork once all work is done. By moving the responsibility you also won't have the described problem.

**Update in response to comments**

What I'm saying is that it's the entry point for the current execution that should be responsible of committing the transaction/uow. It's only that place that knows when the business transaction is done.

For a MVC application the entry point is the MVC controller action. For WCF its the method in the service. For a Windows Service application it might be a timer or a the thread method.

It's only those places that knows if one, two or three different services and/or service methods need to be called to complete the requested functionality.

Comment: Are you saying that UnitOfWork.Commit() shouldn't be called within my services and instead I should wrap it in a function exposed by my service so other services can call that? I don't know how I would feel about it. If that's not the case, could you throw together a simple example or just refactor my code to explain your point please?

Comment: Depends on if your service is an internal service or a web service. You question do not specify that.

Comment: It's an internal service.

Comment: In reference to your updated answer. What do you suggest happens at the WCF / MVC / Windows Service layer, does it call a function which simply wraps the save changes function of my uow? How else could it dictate that it's done doing what ever it's doing?

Comment: I don't understand the question? The service itself is done when it's done, that isn't decided by whether the UoW is committed or not. the service do not decide when the unit of work is done, because the uoW can contain changes made by other services too. The Commit/SaveChanges is just a contract saying "Great, ***everything*** is done, let's persist the changes" and that decision must be made by the top layer.

Comment: But how can it be decided by the top layer if it doesn't have access to the Commit/SaveChanges function? Each service that requires access to the uow contains it's own instance of the uow.

Comment: No, you should pass the instance to the services in the service constructor. It's called dependency injection.